# Running 32-bit Assembly Source files on a 64-bit Ubuntu Linux installation

Tags: linux, ubuntu, assembly, 32bit-64bit

I am trying to run this code that I recieved for one of my classes:

```
#32bit version

#PURPOSE:  Simple program that exits and returns a
#          status code (42) back to the Linux kernel
#
#INPUT:    none
#
#OUTPUT:   returns a status code.  This can be viewed
#          by typing
#
#          echo $?
#

# %eax holds the system call number
# %ebx holds the return status


.section .text
.globl _start
_start:
    movl $1, %eax #1 -> exit
    movl $42, %ebx #return 42
    int $0x80 #run kernel
```

I then assemble, link, and try to run it using:

```
as exit.s -o exit.o
ld exit.o -o exit
./exit
```

which results in a Seg fault. What am I doing wrong? I'm not sure whether it's installation or code related as I am quite new to both assembly and linux. I am getting all the code from the textbook that we are to follow.

I have tried following suggestions online and installed various packages through sudo such as gcc-multilib, g++-multilib, libc:i386, libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386. I also did add the i386 architecture. I have also tried assembling with -m32 but that caused an error. I have found a 64 bit version of the program and it does work but this course is going to be taught in 32 so I would like it to work as well.

I have looked online for a while and haven't found anything that has helped me, as in a lot of questions like the one I have, people are using gcc to compile .c files which (to the best of my knowledge) is not applicable in my situation.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Are you using WSL1?  The 32-bit `int 0x80` doesn't work there.  (The program only runs at all on WSL1 because you built it as a 64-bit executable, the default for `as` and `ld`).  Since you need to use 32-bit code, you need WSL2 or a VM.  [Does WSL 2 really support 32 bit program?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61300194) / [Assembling 32-bit binaries on a 64-bit system (GNU toolchain)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36861903)

Comment: @PeterCordes Thank you so much! My bad for not finding those pages before,  I updated my WSL and everything works. Thanks again I've been going crazy for hours XD

Comment: @Shadows_Puppet You should have said that you are on WSL immediately.  Misrepresenting your system as a real Ubuntu installation is not doing you any favours.